# Multiply model matrix with vector array, Android OpenGL ES

Tags: java, android, matrix, opengl-es

The following code does not seem to correctly transform a float[] array to be passed as uniform vec4[] to the vertex shader. Why isn't this working?

```
private static short STRIDE = 4;    
private final float[] modelMatrix = new float[16];
private float[] worldVertices = new float[12];
private static float[] modelVertices = {1f, 0f, 0f, 1f,
                                        0f, 1f, 0f, 1f,
                                        0f, 0f, 1f, 1f };
setIdentityM(modelMatrix, 0);
```

[compute deltas]

```
translateM(modelMatrix, 0, dx, dy, dz); 

// PROBLEM CODE: 
for (short i = 0; i < 3 * STRIDE; i += STRIDE)
        multiplyMV(worldVertices, i, modelMatrix, 0, modelVertices, i);
```

The worldVertices are then passed to the vertex shader. Replacing the loop with component-wise math produces the correct result. What is the best way to perform the model-vector multiplication to keep the array one-dimensional?

**SOLVED!**

Offset for the source vec4 array doesn't seem to work, it requires a float[4] rHs but can still store the results in a float[4*n] lHs.

```
float[] t = new float[4];

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) t[j] = source[j + i * 4];
    multiplyMV(result, i * 4, Matrix, 0, t, 0);
}
```

Comment: One problem is that you only have 3 vertices, but your loop iterates over 4 vertices.

Comment: Good catch Reto, for loop corrected.